# "Exercise 40: Dictionaries .." in Learn Python The Hard Way: for dictionaries a and b, how does a[b[c]] work?

Tags: python, dictionary, lookup

I'm trying to follow along with Exercise 40 from [Learn Python The Hard Way, 2nd edition"](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Esrini/15-441/F11/LPTHW/lpthw.pdf#page=116), by Zed A. Shaw.

The last snippet of code sets up two dictionaries like so:

```
states = {
'Oregon': 'OR',
'Florida': 'FL',
'California': 'CA',
'New York': 'NY',
'Michigan': 'MI'
}
cities = {
'CA': 'San Francisco',
'MI': 'Detroit',
'FL': 'Jacksonville'
}
```

and then does various things with the dictionary.

I don't understand what is happening at this point in the example:

```
print "Michigan has: ", cities[states['Michigan']]
```

When I try it, the result is `Michigan has:  Detroit`.

**Why**? How does Python link one dictionary with the other?

This is my assumption and understanding I want to verify:

Python reads `cities[states['Michigan']]` backwards. First, it looks through the `states` and finds `Michigan`, then its value. Next it uses this value to look in `cities`, where the value from the state is the key. Finally it prints out the value for the key from `cities`.

Why does it not just print out the key from the cities (`MI`)?

Comment: Well... yeah. What other way did you think it had of evaluating that expression?

Comment: Yes, of course it works that way. You can think of it as, `cities[states['Michigan']]` -> `cities['MI']` -> `'Detroit'`.

Comment: I am sorry, I began to learn a week ago so for someone a silly question its just me learning to code.

Comment: The understanding that was presented, is hard to understand. OP apparently recognized that `states['Michigan']` would compute the **value** associated with that key (`'MI'`), and then use that key to look something up in `cities`; but then apparently expected the result to be **the key** that was used for the second lookup - despite already demonstrating a correct understanding two sentences (after editing) ago. What???

Comment: @KarlKnechtel, thanks for co-editing and demonstrating how a we can express our comprehension-issues along with assumptions into an easy to follow question so others can follow our path of thoughts (like [Thinking Aloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Think_aloud_protocol)). I hope we improved the question while preserving its original intend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how the Python interpreter evaluates the expressions for a dictionary lookup.

1. In following expression it looks for the value of given key `'Michigan'` in the dict `states`:

   `states['Michigan']`

   The resulting value, after evaluating this expression, is `"MI"`.
2. Then it takes this evaluated value and uses it to lookup inside the `cities` dict. Knowing the first expression returned `"MI"` an equivalent lookup expression would be:

   `cities['MI']`

Comment: This clearly illustrates how Python *evaluates lookup-expressions* inside-out. To answer the How-question: "link one dictionary with the other" is incorrect. Rather this chained  lookup is interpreted by Python like 2 consecutive lookups in order. This separate lookups are necessary, because the dictionaries are not linked at all. The only relation they have is written in code like this nested lookup-expression.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not link dictionaries. What it does is in line `cities[states['Michigan']]` it first evaluates `states['Michigan']` to the value of `'Michigan'` in `states` dictionary (which is `'MI'`). After that expression looks like `cities['MI']`. And then it evaluates it to value of `'MI'` from `cities` dictionary (which is `'Detroit'`).

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much.

Comment: We should be careful when explaining with phrases like "looks like". Only for Python and only after lookup during runtime they seem equivalent. This is rather an intermediary state after the first lookup during Python's evaluation process at runtime. Like a snapshot in time. Only at this instant point in runtime, and only because Python knows the mapped abbreviation then, the expression `cities[states['Michigan']]` might be equivalent to `cities['MI']`.

Answer (score 1):

It resolves not quite *backwards*, but in order of innermost expression -> outermost expression.

So, for `cities[states['Michigan']]`, it will

1. Looks at `cities`
2. Recognize it needs to resolve `states['Michigan']`
3. Look at `states`
4. Find `states['Michigan']`
5. Return value of `states['Michigan']` to `cities`
6. Now it can resolve `cities[states['Michigan']]`